# Chance of randomly generated float equality?

Tags: python, random, floating-point

Short version:

How big is chance that floats generated randomly <0,1> will be equal?
I can imagine the number is quite big, but cannot quite do the math myself.

Long version:

I am working on evolutionary algorithm for **"Rectilinear Crossing Number"** problem , where I represent vertex of graph as a set of [x,y] coordinates defined as floats. I want to justify the absurdity of testing for graph edge parallelism to my task supervisor, but I don't want to do so without proper numbers (not to look like an idiot). Or should I **consider giving up performance** to the "anything can happen" situation handling?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"On a typical machine running Python, there are 53 bits of precision available for a [C?]Python float"* - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Note: for generating floats, I am using Python version 3.5.1. with its random.random() function

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth So I can assume(for 2^64) that 2^63 floats are positive and 2^62 are from range I mentioned? That would be quite sufficient I guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you're talking about double-precision floats.  So there are approximately 2^64 unique values.  Approximately half of these are negative (i.e. < 0).  Approximately half of what's left have a positive exponent (i.e. > 1).

So you're left with approximately 2^62 values in the range [0,1).

This is slightly unfair, because picking any of these representations with equal probability won't correspond to a uniform distribution (it will be approximately an exponential distribution).  But even if we just stick with the most naive way to make this uniform (keeping a fixed exponent, and just randomising the mantissa), that's still 2^53 unique values.

Comment: Thanks, 2^23 would be far enough already. I am sorry if the question is naive, but I could not get to the answer myself.

Comment: That gives a good ballpark for the per-trial probability, but if you're going to keep generating pairs you're dealing with a geometric distribution (discrete analogue of a negative exponential) to describe how many unequal pairs you will get before seeing an equality.  The geometric is a skewed distribution and more probability is packed in at the low end, so although 2^62 is the expected length of a run without duplicates the probability of getting a duplicate passes 0.5 earlier  at about 70% of the expected length.  And if sampling is without replacement, you run into the birthday problem.